# Copy constructor throws null value error in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy, shallow-copy

(Been out of touch from cpp too long, wanted to brush up for the interview tomorrow).
Was revising Deep Copy v/s Shallow Copy. Wrote the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    unsigned int* uivar = nullptr;

    MyClass() : uivar(new unsigned int) {
        *(this->uivar) = 3;
    }

    ~MyClass() { delete uivar; }

    MyClass(const MyClass& mCopy) {
        *(uivar) = *(mCopy.uivar);
    }
};

void function(MyClass m) {
    *(m.uivar) = 4;
}

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    MyClass myClassCopy = myClass;
    std::cout << *(myClass.uivar) << "\n";
    std::cout << *(myClassCopy.uivar) << "\n";
    function(myClass);
    std::cout << *(myClass.uivar) << "\n";
    std::cout << "hhhh" << "\n";
    *(myClassCopy.uivar) = 5;
    std::cout << *(myClass.uivar) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Error(-Warn): `Dereferencing NULL pointer uivar` at `*(uivar) = *(mCopy.uivar);`.
What am I missing?

Comment: Copy ctor does not execute the default ctor.

Comment: *wanted to brush up for the interview tomorrow* -- Your code lacks a user-defined assignment operator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yeah, I know... I'm f*ed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your copy constructor is not correct, it would need to allocate its own pointer

```
MyClass(const MyClass& mCopy) {
    uivar = new unsigned int(*mCopy.uivar);
}
```

Comment: oops brain fart... thanks man!

Comment: This might be a separate question in itself, but can shallow copy be achieved with a normal `unsigned int` rather than a pointer? The default for a "normal" variable happens to be deep copy unlike pointers where the default is shallow...

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him Unlike with pointers, there is no "deep" for `unsigned int`, it is all right there. So in the non-pointer unsigned int case there is no distinction between a shallow and a deep copy.